# How To Kill All Child Process and Restart Every 1 hour in C#

Tags: c#

I have a C# program that sends a `HttpWebRequest` every milliseconds to get some currency quotes. But, to my surprise yesterday, it freeze up my server and make the CPU go way too higher like a DDOS is being sent to my Server.

It call a Java Process also to update some functions...
This is how i currently kill my Java Processes:

```
Process[] processesByName = Process.GetProcessesByName("java");
    for (int i = 0; i < (int)processesByName.Length; i++)
            {
                processesByName[i].Kill();
            }
```

**How is the best way to kill all Child Process like the Java Processes and kill all threads at a go every hour?**

Thanks...

Comment: why don't you fix the underlying problem?

Comment: @DanielA.White: Because the OP can't see the downside of his/her current approach. Let's show them. Otw, I agree with you and have up-voted your comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try and improve your design. One way could be:

---

### At the client side

The client should subscribe to the server and simply listen to the values being returned from the server. Also, a client should keep sending a simple acknowledgement packet to the server at regular intervals to let it know that it is alive.

---

### At the server side

Let server keep a list of the client's addresses who have subscribed to the information for a particular currency. Then on, it can keep sending the latest about that currency to all the clients who have subscribed for it. It can cancel the subscription of those clients who haven't sent an acknowledgment in a long enough time, assuming that they aren't alive anymore.

---

### Benefits

You don't flood the server with requests. Instead you tell it to start or stop the sending the currency info. This reduces the messaging. And hopefully solves your other problem too.